# Variable not updating outside of Function in JS/Asynchronous Issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am currently facing an issue with my program. My problem is essentially that my variable `cityCounting` in controller.js is not updating outside of the function clickCounter.

So clickCounter is counting the number of clicks I hit a button, and from there I want the # of clicks to represent the different city names I would parse would in the array named categories as shown in categories.js. Once I got the city name I would use that city in my API call. That is why I currently have an if/else statement for the stringing the API URL. One of the conditions is meant for another function, while this particular function is focusing on the "else" portion.

I got to the point where I know clickCounter is working properly, but it's not updating outside of the function.

I've googled a lot and it seems to be an asynchronous problem? Please correct me if I'm wrong, but even with the googling and looking at similar questions, I don't know what I should be doing.

Should I be using promises? Or .then()? Any input/examples would definitely be helpful. Thank you!

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('weatherApp.controllers', [])

.controller('weatherCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var vm = $scope;

  $http.get("http://ip-api.com/json").success(function(data) {

    var categories = [
          {"id": 1, "city": "Boston"},
          {"id": 2, "city": "New York"},
          {"id": 3, "city": "Seattle"},
          {"id": 4, "city": "Los Angeles"},
          {"id": 5, "city": "Miami"},
          {"id": 6, "city": "Fresno"},
          {"id": 7, "city": "Tracy"},
          {"id": 8, "city": "Portland"},
          {"id": 9, "city": "Norfolk"},
          {"id": 10, "city": "San Francisco"},
      ];


    var city = data.city;
      var cityCounting = 0;

    var counter = 0;

  $scope.clickCounter =function () {
      cityCounting = counter++;
      console.log(cityCounting);
      return cityCounting;
    }
    console.log(cityCounting);

    if(cityCounting == 0){
      var apiKey = "";//removed
    var openWeatherURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + ",us" + "&appid=" + apiKey;
    console.log("no im from city original here");
    }
    else{
      var apiKey = "";
    var openWeatherURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityCounting + ",us" + "&appid=" + apiKey;
        console.log("no im from city counting");
    }
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<md-button addbuttons ng-click='clickCounter()' class='md-fab md-mini'>+</md-button>
```

Here is the code of the portion I am talking about https://jsfiddle.net/zvdr4wy2/

Comment: You have a syntax error. Also, `success` is considered obsolete - use promises instead - and you ought to move the $http call into a separate service, since it's better practice. But first, fix the syntax error.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen can you point out where

Comment: You can check it in your browser console. It'll look like this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. It's probably just something that crept up while copying code to stack overflow, but until you fix it, there's no point trying to answer the question.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen thank you for pointing that out! I just fixed the error. Any input you have would definitely be appreciated!